# How to detect if dark dark mode is on in fb in-app browser?

Tags: css, facebook, mode

For normal browsers we have query:

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

}

But this in not working for fb in-app browser, anyone knows a way to detect it there?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's in-app browser uses a so-called WebView to render the content. On Android, WebViews *can* support `prefers-color-scheme`, but it looks like Facebook haven't set the [`DARK_STRATEGY_PREFER_WEB_THEME_OVER_USER_AGENT_DARKENING`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/webkit/WebSettingsCompat#DARK_STRATEGY_PREFER_WEB_THEME_OVER_USER_AGENT_DARKENING:kotlin.Int) mode that would be necessary for this to work. If Facebook doesn't change this, the only solution is to use a proper browser.